# Cómo personalizar el login del spring-security-plugin en grails

Tags: postgresql, spring-security, grails, plugin

Comunidad:
Recientemente he comenzado el trabajo con el plugin spring-security-core-2.0 para grail(2.5.3). Me gustaría personalizar la ventana de logueo que tiene por defecto y cambiar algunas configuraciones para que redireccione a las paginas que deseo. Como podría modificar el DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy que viene por defecto en el plugin?.
En Config.groovy tengo

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.webapp.seguridad.Usuario'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.webapp.seguridad.UsuarioRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.webapp.seguridad.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   '/':                ['permitAll'],
   '/index':           ['permitAll'],
   '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
   '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
   '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
   '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
   '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
   '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll']
]
```

Además me gustaría saber como puedo utilizar los usuarios desde una Base de datos en PostgresSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El plugin >= 2.0 trae su propia pagina auth.gsp por lo que si quieres crear la tuya propia puedes escribir un archivo auth.gsp y ubicarlo en  app/views/login/auth.gsp para ser usado.

Comment: si, el redirecciona hacia la main.gsp, dentro de view/layouts, ahi puse la configuracion del auth.gsp, sin embargo quiero conectarme con usuarios almacenados en la BD de postgres y que redirrecione a la pagian que deseo